# Extracting Summary Statistics value with cursor and assigning it to a variable

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, statistics, nameerror

I am writing a script (to be used in ArcGIS 10.7.1) that uses a Zonal Statistics tool to create an average of a raster that is beneath a grid. I then use the Summary Statistics tool to take the summation of all the grid values and display them in a table. The resulting table has only one row with three columns, as shown below:

[image]

I'm trying to use a cursor to assign the value of the "SUM_Value" to a variable, because that value will be used later to compute some fertilizer amounts.

**How can I do this?**

The methods that I've tried aren't working out. I get this error when I do so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 1, in <module>
    totalNitrogen = row.getValue(field)
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
#Define workspace
env.workspace = "C:\\someWorkspace"

#Defining variable 'Grid'
Grid = #Previously created grid

#Zonal statistics tool
recommendationMap = ZonalStatistics(Grid, "grid_field", outputRaster, "MEAN")

#Compute raster to Int
recommendationMapInt = Int(recommendationMap)

#Save raster
recommendationMapInt.save(env.workspace + "\\nitrogenRecommendationMap")

#Generate statistics with Summary Statistics tool
nitrogenStats = arcpy.Statistics_analysis(recommendationMapInt,"outputRaster",[["Field_to_summarize", "SUM"]])

#Resulting output field defined for cursor
nitrogenField = "SUM_Value"

#Cursor defined
nitrogenCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(nitrogenStats)

#Error occurs here
totalNitrogen = row.getValue(field)
```

As previously stated, I need that `totalNitrogen` variable to equal the "SUM_Value" field from the `Statistics_analysis` table.

Comment: Only mistake that I can see is that you are not defining row object after your cursor. Presuming you will always have one row in your Summary Statistics, if you say `row = nitrogenCursor.next()` after your `nitrogenCursor` assignment,  you will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're not iterating your cursor so `row` is never set, you *should* be using [an arcpy.da cursor](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) like:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(nitrogenStats,"SUM_Value") as nitrogenCursor: 
  for row in nitrogenCursor: 
    totalNitrogen = row[0] 
    break # to ensure we only read the first value exit the loop
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
totalNitrogen = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(nitrogenStats,'SUM_Value')][0]
```

Which creates a list of all the values in the table but then assigns totalNitrogen as the first element.

If you insist on using the old style cursor it can be achieved like:

```
nitrogenCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(nitrogenStats)
for row in nitrogenCursor:
  totalNitrogen = row.getValue(field)
  break # to ensure we only read the first value exit the loop
del nitrogenCursor # important to release locks.
```